# Probability Given Three Ranges for Variables in an Equation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, physics

In physics, I learned that the equation
\begin{align*}
|\textbf{R}| = \frac{Gm_{1}m_{2}}{r^{2}}
\end{align*}
is used to solve for the force of gravity between two different masses ($G$ = Newton's gravitational constant, $m_{1}$ = mass 1, $m_{2}$ = mass 2, $r$ = distance between objects).

Given a range for $m_{1}$, $m_{2}$, and $r$, how can I find the probability that once the variables are plugged into the equation, it will exceed a certain number? I found something about [the probability of the union of three sets](https://www.thoughtco.com/probability-union-of-three-sets-more-3126263), but I don't know if this can be applied to my scenario.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: think of a problem where you roll three dice. Now find the probability that some function of the numbers on those three dice exceed a particular value.

Comment: If your values are chosen uniformly from the corresponding ranges $[a,b], [c,d], [e,f]$, what you need is a fraction of volumes in the $(m_1,m_2,r)$-space. Namely, the ratio of the volume of the intersection of the parellelepiped $[a,b]\times [c,d]\times [e,f]$ with the region $|F|\ge k$ to the volume $(b-a)(d-c)(f-e)$ of the parallelepiped itself. So your question reduces to finding a triple integral for the volume of the intersection.

Comment: You need to specify how the values are distributed. For instance, they could be independently uniformly distributed over their ranges.

Comment: They are independent sets I believe. I’m not sure what they’d be classified as, but it’s just sliders on Desmos.